# Lambda calculus closure expansion

Tags: reference-request, lambda-calculus

The set of lambda calculus expressions $Expr$ is generated by the grammar
$$
 Expr \ni e ::= x \mid \lambda x\ldotp e \mid e_1 e_2
$$

We can define an interpreter without explicit substitution by using *environments* and *closures*:
$$
  \begin{align*}
  Env &= Var \rightharpoonup Cl &\text{($\rightharpoonup$ is partial function space)}\\
  Cl &= Env \times Expr
  \end{align*}
$$

The evaluation function $eval : Env \times Expr \to Cl$ sends each expression in a given environment to an evaluated closure:

$$
\begin{align*}
  eval_\rho(x) =& \rho(x) \\
  eval_\rho(\lambda x\ldotp e) =& (\rho, \lambda x\ldotp e) \\
  eval_\rho(e_1 e_2) =& \mathrm{let~}eval_\rho(e_1) = (\rho', \lambda x\ldotp e_1') \\
   & \mathrm{in~} eval_{\rho'[x \mapsto eval_\rho(e_2)]}(e_1')
\end{align*}
$$

Using substitution, a closure $(\rho, e) \in Cl$ can be expanded to yield the represented expression:
$$F([x_1 \mapsto c_1, ..., x_n \mapsto c_n], e) = e[F(c_1)/x_1, ..., F(c_n)/x_n]$$
This however forgets all sharing. E.g., $F([x \mapsto ([], f)], x x) = f f$ duplicates the expression $f$, which might be very large. An alternative expansion retains sharing:

$$
G([x_1 \mapsto e_1, ..., x_n \mapsto e_n],e) = (\lambda x_1 \ldotp \cdots (\lambda x_n \ldotp e) \cdots) ~G(e_1)~\cdots ~ G(e_n)
$$

This on the other hand repeats definitions in nested scopes, e.g.:
$$
  G([x\mapsto ([],f), y \mapsto ([x \mapsto ([],f)], g)], x y) \\
  = (\lambda x\ldotp \lambda y\ldotp xy)~(f)~((\lambda x\ldotp g)~f)
$$
An equivalent but more economical expansion that doesn't duplicate $g$ would be
$$
  (\lambda x\ldotp (\lambda y\ldotp xy) g)~f
$$
For practical purposes, if one wants to "render" a closure as a plain expression, both $F$ and $G$ are unsatisfactory: The closure environments can be efficiently represented by pointer datastructures that takes avantage of sharing, but most of that sharing seems to be lost with either approach.

- Do you know of any efficient data structures and algorithms related to this problem?
- Is this problem called something more specific in the literature? I tried search for "lambda calculus closure expansion", but without much success.

Comment: I'm not sure but it sounds somewhat like you'd be interested in "optimal evaluation" e.g. [Lamping's work](https://doi.org/10.1145/96709.96711) and work that descended from it. These discussions might point you at other related topics: [reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2zqtfk/why_isnt_anyone_talking_about_optimal_lambda/), [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707614/why-are-%CE%BB-calculus-optimal-evaluators-able-to-compute-big-modular-exponentiation)

Comment: This definitely seems relevant, I wasn't aware of this work. Thank you!